# Is this crypto code thread safe?

Tags: java, encryption, thread-safety

I have a pool of immutable encryption helper objects which contain instances of the java JCA Cipher and MessageDigest objects:

```
AlgorithmInstance( Cipher encCipher, Cipher decCipher, MessageDigest digest ) { ... }
private BlockingQueue< AlgorithmInstance > pool = new ArrayBlockingQueue< AlgorithmInstance >(poolSize);
```

Various threads in my application, needing encryption or decryption, contend for AlgorithmInstance objects by accessing a pool.  Each thread uses them to encrypt or decrypt, and then returns them to the pool when they are done.  Threads don't synchronize on any of JCA objects since there is no concurrent access.  Decrypt works roughly the same way.

```
public byte[] encryptMessage( byte data[] ) { ...
 try {
  AlgorithmInstance inst = pool.take();

  inst.digest.reset(); 
  byte[] digest = inst.digest.digest(message);

  inst.encryptCipher.init( Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, m_currentKey, ivParams );
  inst.encryptCipher.doFinal( messageBuffer );
 }
 finally {
  pool.put(inst)
 }
}
```

This works 99.99% of the time; and 100% of the time in unit tests.  However, once in a blue moon, I get a message whose computed digest does not come out right -- normally this indicates message tampering or network errors; but sender and receiver are on the same machine (in different processes).

**Q:** Is there some internal state for a Cipher or Digest which can suffer from memory consistency effects -- I'm on a 2 core windows box so I don't see how I could even suffer from memory consistency effects.  I re-initialize the cipher and digest each call so it should not matter.

**Q:** Is there any way I could have ended up with a padding mode that sometimes fails based on the message length?  The decryptor and encryptor use exactly the same algorithms (AES/CBC/Pkcs5Padding + SHA-256, and a key size of 128).

Comment: Answer 1: Not that I can see. Answer 2: No.

Comment: My feeling is that its some side effect of class GC or some shared buffer in the Ciphers/Digests; or as @Rook suggests i'm using it wrong.  It happened again, and the digests were totally different not just a few bits different.  Absolutely no idea.

Comment: Is there are reason you pool them at all? Does it really give a performance benefit? I would have guessed that creating the cyper objects wouldn't be that expensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code so that I synchronize on the AlgorithmInstance while I use any of its contained objects.  I have not seen this problem since; however its not clear why; since the `queue.put()` and `queue.take()` operations should form EXACTLY the same *happens-before* relationship formed by the monitor unlock:

```
synchronized (inst) {
 ...
 // do crypto opperations
}
```

The only other possibility I can come up with is that the IVParamSpec is modified during the Cipher.init() computation and then restored at the end.  Since the ivParams are assumed read only and shared across all objects in the pool, if true, this could lead to un-synchronized access and possibly MCE.

Comment: I also went from JDK 1.6_21 -> 1.6_22

Comment: Hi Justin! Did you dig deeper into this? I'm about to write code almost identical to your original version, and would like to avoid any pitfalls. As far as I can tell, the code you first posted should work just fine. Even if `ivParams` were mutable, synchronizing on `inst` shouldn't make any difference, right?

Comment: I cannot distinguish between the JVM upgrade and the synchronized block.  After doing both, no problems.  I could not find a root cause, sadly.

Answer (score 3):

Does your app have a lot of threads? Because instead of having a pool, you could put your AlgorithmInstances in ThreadLocal objects, thus making sure each AlgorithmInstance is only used by the same thread all the time, so the problem should disappear and you won't need to synchronize on the AlgorithmInstance either (so you'll get better performance).

Answer (score 0):

The `encryptMessage()` function its self is thread safe because its not using memory shared by 2 threads.  However,  its likely that the code that is using this function is not thread safe.  If you want to concurrently encrypt/decrypt data within a pool or que,  then its likely that the "current working index" is not incrementing or decrementing in a thread safe manner.   A global index shared between threads can be created by have a global integer protected by a mutex.   Before this value is read and then changed a thread must request a lock on this variable.

Comment: It was not clear from my original post but the pool is an ArrayBlockingQueue.  Are you saying that the pool is the problem?  Any BlockingQue is supposed to be threadsafe: from the javadoc  `Memory consistency effects: As with other concurrent collections, actions in a thread prior to placing an object into a BlockingQueue  happen-before  actions subsequent to the access or removal of that element from the BlockingQueue in another thread. `

Comment: @Justin Crypto isn't magic,  its just some binary operations on a string.  This question is like asking is `.substring()` thread safe?

Comment: So are you saying that the pool is the problem?  BTW, most Ciphers allocate lots of internal tables so there is the potential for MCE.

Comment: @Justin I haven't used that pool before so i'm not sure. Your try might be suppressing a real exception.   Its bad practice to have a catch all,  the code could be excepting and then trying to  `pool.put(inst)` even though the code failed.

Comment: There is no catch all, its try/finally.